# How do I get the selected item from a dropdown to save to my document in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Creating a students profile page, and I want to save my user's input into a firebase doc. Currently, when a user inputs text data (for ex. name) it saves to firebase, but when they select an item from a dropdown it does not save, but the year field is generated.

Here is how I am calling the dropdown:

```
<div>Year:</div>
                    <DropdownYear
                        className={classes.yearDropdown}
                        // onClick={setYear}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            setYear(event.target.value)
                        }}
                    ></DropdownYear>
```

Here is how I am creating the dropdown:

```
return (
             <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    <select
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    >
                        <option value="default">Year</option>
                        <option value="freshman">Freshman</option>
                        <option value="sophomore">Sophomore</option>
                        <option value="junior">Junior</option>
                        <option value="senior">Senior</option>
                        <option value="graduate">Graduate</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default dropdownYear
```

This is what loads the value into firebase.

```
const [year, setYear] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
        const getStudents = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(studentsCollectionRef)
            //loop through documents in collection
            setStudents(
                data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), key: doc.id }))
            )
        }
        getStudents()
    }, [studentsCollectionRef])
    const classes = useStyles()
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share the part that is responsible for uploading the selected value to firebase (or what you've tried so far)? The snippet you posted seems to be correct.

Comment: sure I will edit the post to include that bit since I can't post it in the comments.

Comment: if you log `event.target.value` what are you getting? If you check the state `year` in React Developer tools, are you able to change it and is it displayed? because if you see the right value, as long as it's saved on the state, should be good for Firebase